# Java Comparable interface: compareTo int attributes

Tags: java, interface

Two objects of the same type each have int attributes called intValue. How can the Comparable interface be used to compare these two objects on the basis of their intValue int values?

```
  public int compareTo(myObject other) {
    return (this.intValue).compareTo(other.intValue);
  }
```

```
firstObject.compareTo(secondObject);
```

This produces the error

```
error: int cannot be dereferenced
```

Comment: Which version of Java do you use?

Comment: And post exact error.

Comment: Version 8. Exact error is in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that your `myObject` class implements the `Comparable` interface:

```
public class myObject implements Comparable<myObject>
```

If you're deducing the value returned by `compareTo` using primitive `int` values, you could use the `Integer.compare` method:

```
public int compareTo(myObject other) {
    return Integer.compare(this.intValue, other.intValue);  
}
```

This is logically the same as using `Integer.valueOf` in conjuction with `compareTo`:

```
public int compareTo(myObject other) {
    return Integer.valueOf(this.intValue).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(other.intValue));
}
```

Comment: I tried this method already and it returns the error,  error: myObject is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(Object) in Comparable

Comment: You need to make sure your `myObject` class implements the `Comparable<myObject>` interface.   i.e.  `public class myObject implements Comparable<myObject>`

Comment: This comment is the solution. I did not include the <myObject> part of it. If you could edit your answer say that then I can accept it.

Comment: Sure thing. Glad to help.